# iptables: how to allow genuine internal traffic whilst blocking spoofed/bogus packets?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, iptables

So I've read that a common attack is spoofing packets from internal SRC IP addresses, such as `192.168.0.0/16`. How can I defend against this with iptables, yet at the same time allow traffic from the router or anything else essential?

If I just added a `-s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP` to the INPUT chain that would kill genuine internal traffic too?

Answer (score 1):

One simple answer.  Specify the interface for rules... not just the source IP/ports.

for example

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

(assuming  `eth0` is your WAN interface)

Comment: Thanks, how does this know these are "spoofed", i.e. come from the external, big bad internet rather than being genuine internal packets (e.g. from my router)? (just wondering....)

Comment: Forgive my ignorance: is `eth0` the router then? Hence with your rules above, we know that if say `192.168.0.80` is coming on `eth0` then it's an external packet hitting the router yet pretending to on local network?

Comment: So on reflection `eth0` appears to my wired laptop network card, whereas `eth1` is my wireless laptop network card. I am connecting from the wireless `eth1` device..All traffic is coming through `eth1` though, whether the src is external or whether its say the router on `192.168.1.254`. Hence using `-i eth1` would drop `192.168.0.0/16` for both genuine internal packets and external spoofs?

Comment: Sorry for the long-delay.  These firewall rules should be applied *IN* the router.  Not on a laptop.  A laptop would have no way of knowing if this came from the Internet or from the local network.  As a rule, spoofed packets should never make it past your router.